# Verify that a sequence is a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to understand the nature of the following expression:
$\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
s_n=s_{n-1}+x_n
\end{equation}$
where 
$$x_n=\dfrac{1}{2}m_n^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{4\lambda_{k,n}}\right)^{0.5}+2m_m\sum_{i=n-1}^1m_i\left(\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{4(\lambda_{k,n}+\lambda_{k,i})}\right)^{0.25}$$
and $$x_1= \dfrac{1}{2}m_1^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{4\lambda_{k,1}}\right)^{0.5}.$$Both $\lambda$ and $m$ are positive scalars. My attempt to characterize the convergence of this expression was considering $s_{n+1}=s_{n}+x_{n+1}$ as a recursive sequence of the form $s_{n+1}=f(s_n)$ and so solve the relation $l=f(l)$, where $l= \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}s_{n}$. But now I wonder is $s_{n+1}=f(s_n)$ a recursive sequence?

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, and so is more likely to attract downvotes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: $s_{n+1} = f(s_{n})$ => $s_{n+1} = f(f(s_{n-1}))$

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman I am not sure to have understood your implication. Can you please explain it?

Comment: What I meant is $s_{n+1} = f(s_{n})$ means $s_{n-1+1} = f(s_{n-1})$ by replacing $n$ with $n-1$ and i.e $s_{n} = f(s_{n-1})$, So $s_{n+1} = f(s_{n}) = f(f(s_{n-1}))$

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman As your implication comes from $s_{n+1}= f(s_n)$, this means that do you think that my expression $s_{n}= s_{n-1}+x_{n}$ can be seen as a recursive sequence. Is it true?

Comment: Yes it is a recursive sequence